# JavaScript: DRY mouseover/mouseout event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, handler

This is my code:

```
    $rows
        .on('mouseover', '.row', function () {
            $(this).find('.label').show();
        })
        .on('mouseout', '.row', function () {
            $(this).find('.label').hide();
        });
```

Can it be DRYed out?

Comment: you want to upvote yourself?

Comment: why is that you are asking a question and answering itself at the same moment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind both events, listen to `event.name` and then use [jQuery.fn.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$userRows.on('mouseover mouseout', '.row', function(event) {
    $(this).find(".label").toggle( event.name == "mouseover" );
});
```

Im pretty sure you can also use [jQuery.fn.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$userRows.on('hover', '.row', function(event) {
    $(this).find(".label").toggle( event.name == "mouseenter" );
});
```

or even:

```
$userRows.on('hover', '.row', function(event) {
    $(this).find(".label").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

> $rows.hover(
>      function(){
>          $(this).find('.label').toggle();
>      },
>      function(){
>          $(this).find('.label').toggle();
>      }
>      );